# Get complete Envers revisions where a particular object is affected

Tags: jpa, hibernate-envers

The way revision data is stored each object affected by a revision gets a separate record in the `_AUD` table. So when I search for revisions affecting object `A`, I will get back the entry where revision is `3` for object `B`, but if objects `A` and/or `C` were also changed in revision `3`, those entries aren't returned, giving the impression that `B` was the only object modified in that revision. What I'm trying to do is for each revision affecting object `B`, return all objects affected by that revision.

```
something_AUD     desired     actual

id|REV            id|REV      id|REV
-------------     -------     ------
A|1               B|2         B|2
B|2               B|3         B|3
B|3               C|3
C|3
```

I've been trying to do this by running an initial query to find the relevant revisions:

```
AuditQuery query = AuditReaderFactory.get(entity.em()).createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity(type, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entity.id));
```

and then running the following query for each result:

```
int rev_id = ((RevisionData) data[1]).getId();
AuditQuery q = AuditReaderFactory.get(JPA.em()).createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity(type, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(rev_id));
List<Object[]> real_data = q.getResultList();
```

but this is resulting in a `QuerySyntaxException`:

> Duplicate definition of alias 'r' [select e, r, r from
>   models.AgentShift_AUD e, models.RevisionData r, models.RevisionData r
>   where e.originalId.REV.id in (:_p0) and e.originalId.REV.id = r.id and
>   e.originalId.REV.id in (:_p1) and e.originalId.REV.id = r.id order by
>   e.originalId.REV.id asc, e.originalId.REV.id asc]

I've tried several variations of this which have all led to the same "Duplicate definition of alias 'r'". Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Not sure what your mean by: "but if other entities were also affected by those revisions, those entries are not returned". An example would help understanding what you are trying to achieve and the problems you are facing.

Comment: Added after the update: I don't think you can do that with the envers api, you'd have to use JPA as you're trying to query from multiple tables in a single query: http://ezingsoft.com/?p=52

Comment: Does entity `B` have some relation association with entity `A` and `C`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with so far. It not the cleanest solution but it works:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entity.em());
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery()
.forRevisionsOfEntity(type, false, true)
.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entity.id));

List<Object[]> raw_results = query.getResultList();
List<Object[]> complete_results = new ArrayList<Object[]>(raw_results.size());

for (Object[] data : raw_results) {
    int rev_id = ((RevisionData) data[1]).getId();
    AuditQuery q = reader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(type, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(rev_id));
    List<Object[]> real_data = q.getResultList();
    complete_results.addAll(real_data);
}
```

Hopefully someone will come up with a better way, especially one that can do it in a single query.